# What data is stored in the Sharepoint 2010 content database?

Tags: content-database

What is stored in the content database.  It it only list & library data or absolutely everything. e.g. site collection info, sub sites, pages, images, libraries, web parts, schemas etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Content databases store all content for a site collection. This includes site documents or files in document libraries, list data, Web Part properties, audit logs, and sandboxed solutions, in addition to user names and rights. All of the files that are stored for a specific site collection are located in one content database on only one server. A content database can be associated with more than one site collection.

Below are some of the basic tables within a content database and a very high level diagram on some of the relationships between them.

**Features:**

Table that holds information about all the activated features for each site collection or site.

**Sites:**

Table that holds information about all the site collections for this content database.

**Webs:**

Table that holds information about all the specific sites (webs) in each site collection.

**UserInfo**

Table that holds information about all the users for each site collection.

**Groups:**

Table that holds information about all the SharePoint groups in each site collection.

**Roles:**

Table that holds information about all the SharePoint roles (permission levels) for each site.

**All Lists:**

Table that holds information about lists for each site.

**GroupMembership:**

Table that holds information about all the SharePoint group members.

**AllUserData:**

Table that holds information about all the list items for each list.

**AllDocs:**

Table that holds information about all the documents (and all list items) for each document library and list.

**RoleAssignment:**

Table that holds information about all the users or SharePoint groups that are assigned to roles.

**Sched Subscriptions:** Table that holds information about all the scheduled subscriptions (alerts) for each user.

**ImmedSubscriptions**

Table that holds information about all the immediate subscriptions (alerts) for each user.

[image]

Comment: So is anything stored on the file system at all for a site collection? E.g. css files

Comment: 14 hive is the location on file system in which data related to SharePoint are stored. For more information on what all is stored in 14 hive(14 for SP2010 and 15 for SP2013), please refer this link. http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-14-hive-directory-structure.html